# Show a summation is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

> Let
>
> $$f(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{2n^2-\sin(nx)}$$
>
> 1. Decide whether $f$ is continuous
> 2. Is $f$ differentiable

What theorems do I use to solve this?

Comment: Where is there $x$ in the right-hand side? and is $N=n$ ?

Comment: Sorry spell check

Comment: What in the world is $\sin (N.C.)?$

Comment: What is the domain of $f(x)$??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence

Comment: @tourism $\Bbb R$, as pointwise convergence is quite obvious.

Comment: $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The theorems you want to use are the ones you've been studying. Weierstrass M test for one. Please show us what you have tried, your thoughts on this, etc. Otherwise it may look as if you want us to solve your homework problem with no effort on your part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that $2n^{2}-\sin (nx) \geq 2n^{2}-1$ to see that the series converges uniformly.  Next consider $\sum \frac {d} {dx} (\frac 1 {2n^{2}-\sin (nx)})$ and show that this series also converges uniformly. Now use the following:

Theorem

If $f_n \to f$ uniformly where $f_n$'s are continuously differentiable and if $f_n' \to g$ uniformly then $f$ is differentiable and  $f'(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.

[Apply this theorem to the partial sums of the series].

Comment: The inequality should be $\ge$.